# short2, 10 bit integer, 5 bit fraction, one sign bit

Tags: c++, math, nvidia, fixed-point, opticalflow

NVIDIA's Optical Flow library documentation states the flow vectors are "*represented by a 32-bit value with each horizontal and vertical compoment being 16-bit value. The lowest 5 bits holding fractional value, followed by a 10-bit integer value and the most significant bit being a sign bit*".

So, with the short2 type:

```
struct __device_builtin__ __align__(4) short2
{
    short x, y;
};
```

How would I extract two floats, with the correct sign?  My attempt here I don't find all that convincing.  At least my motion vectors don't look right.  One thing I'm not sure about is whether it's two's compliment or not.  The document doesn't say.

```
struct MotionVector {
    float x;
    float y;
};

float ExtractSingleMotionValue(short value) {
    bool isNegative = (value & 0x8000) != 0; // Check the sign bit

    // Clear the sign bit
    value = value & 0x7FFF;

    // Extract integer part (10 bits)
    int intPart = (value >> 5);

    // Extract fractional part (5 bits)
    float fracPart = value & 0x001F;
    fracPart /= 32;  // Convert fractional part to actual decimal

    float result = intPart + fracPart;

    if (isNegative) {
        result = -result;
    }

    return result;
}

MotionVector ExtractMotionVector(short2 value) {
    MotionVector mv;

    mv.x = ExtractSingleMotionValue(value.x);
    mv.y = ExtractSingleMotionValue(value.y);

    return mv;
}
```

Can anyone offer some advice?  I really don't like my solution.  I'm sure there's a single line one out there.

Comment: `x/32.f, y/32.f` -- let me know if that's enough of an answer for you

Comment: It's not clear if the "fixed point" number is 2s complement (like an `int`) or sign bitflag (like a `float`).  If it is 2s complement, Christoph's comment will work for both positive and negative.  If it is "like a float", then you'd want to check-and-mask the sign bit, and multiply the result by `-1.0f` if the sign bit indicates negative.

Comment: they're nvidia. they won't do anything silly. I'd bet it's x/32.f because it's fixed point format, as usual in image processing and whatnot

Comment: It's CUDA and I know GPUs have a 16 bit float type.  It's probably that isn't it.  I wonder if it's a __half.  Scratch that.  IEEE® 754 is mantissa, exponent, not fixed point.

Comment: no. categorically no. they do not talk of an exponent and mantissa.

Comment: I didn't bother voting. your code shows that you spent some effort exploring the problem, which puts your question *above* the type of questions that deserve downvotes. you could have just fed the API some synthetic or known data (pair or pictures with known flow) and looked at what it does. treat it as a black box, test your hypothesis against the data. you would have noticed the issue with values for flow vectors going -x or -y pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/optical-flow-sdk/nvofa-programming-guide/index.html#generating-flow-vectors

> Flow vector is preresented by a 32-bit value with each horizontal and vertical compoment being 16-bit value. The lowest 5 bits holding fractional value, followed by a 10-bit integer value and the most significant bit being a sign bit.

That is a fixed point format. All the bits are mantissa*. The decimal point is fixed at 5 fractional bits. 2<sup>5</sup> = 32. That's the required "shift"/divisor.

Interpret it like so:

```
short x_raw;
float x_pixels = x_raw * (1.f / 32);
```

<sub>*) let's not argue about the sign... OK let's</sub>

Granted, they failed to specify how negative values are represented. From my experience, two's complement is the obvious choice, resulting in concise code and no acrobatics required in the arithmetic. Any other format is a war crime.

This is not a *floating point* format. There is no mention of an exponent or mantissa.

Comment: OK, I have done that so I must have a bug elsewhere, as my vectors are still all skewed.  I will press on.

Comment: do feel free to post that situation, including any raw data. raw data is format-agnostic. everyone has ways to read raw data.

Comment: Digging around, I found some code in their sample and this is what they're effectively doing, e.g. : flowData[2 * linearIndex] = (float)(_flowVectors[linearIndex].flowx / float(1 << 5));